# copy the names of DNA sequences in a phylogenetic tree file and add the names of the species to it

Tags: text-processing, grep, scripting, bioinformatics

From a file looking like this one :

```
(AJirio_TR15329|c4_g1_i4|m.30470:0.00230,(AJama_TR16613|c5_g2_i2|m.30203:0.00171,(AJkago_TR11651|c5_g2_i1|m.3847:0.00057,AJtok_TR11413|c7_g1_i1|m.3527:0.00033)1.00    :0.00080)0.94    :0.00085,Atab_TR15364|c0_g1_i1|m.4073:0.27697);
```

I need to obtain this file :

```
AJirio_TR15329|c4_g1_i4|m.30470"AJirio"  
AJama_TR16613|c5_g2_i2|m.30203"AJama"
AJkago_TR11651|c5_g2_i1|m.3847"AJkago"
AJtok_TR11413|c7_g1_i1|m.3527"AJtok"
Atab_TR15364|c0_g1_i1|m.4073"Atab"
```

So basically extract the name of the DNA sequences in a phylogenetic tree and add the name of the species (AJirio, AJkama..) with quotation marks to it.

Comment: The entry `AJtok_TR11413|c7_g1_i1|m.3527:0.00033)1.00    :0.00080)0.94    :0.00085` differs from the others.  Can you explain what you want to happen here?

Comment: elaborate your output: why it should output the single number `30470` in one case and the sequence `3847:0.00057` in another?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest oups, it was a mistake I just edited

Comment: @Andy Dalton I don't understand your question, it's just how the phylogenetic tree is made but that's not important.

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -v RS=',' -F':' '{ 
           sub(/^\(/, "", $1); 
           printf "%s\042%s\042\n", $1, substr($1, 1, index($1,"_")-1) 
       }' file
```

- `RS=','` - treating `,` as record separator
- `-F':'` - treating `:` as field separator
- `sub(/^\(/, "", $1)` - remove the leading brace from the 1st field `$1`
- `\042` - octal ASCII code of the double quote char `"`
- `substr($1, 1, index($1,"_")-1)` - extracting the *name of the species* from the 1st field (from the starting position `1` till the first occurrence of `_` char)

---

The output:

```
AJirio_TR15329|c4_g1_i4|m.30470"AJirio"
AJama_TR16613|c5_g2_i2|m.30203"AJama"
AJkago_TR11651|c5_g2_i1|m.3847"AJkago"
AJtok_TR11413|c7_g1_i1|m.3527"AJtok"
Atab_TR15364|c0_g1_i1|m.4073"Atab"
```

Comment: I really need to learn more awk :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get you what you want:

The input file:

```
$ cat input
(AJirio_TR15329|c4_g1_i4|m.30470:0.00230,(AJama_TR16613|c5_g2_i2|m.30203:0.00171,(AJkago_TR11651|c5_g2_i1|m.3847:0.00057,AJtok_TR11413|c7_g1_i1|m.3527:0.00033)1.00    :0.00080)0.94    :0.00085,Atab_TR15364|c0_g1_i1|m.4073:0.27697);
```

The script to translate the input to output.  The script uses `tr` to translate commas to line breaks, then uses `sed` to eliminate all spaces, all parentheses, and to remove everything after a `:` on a line, then uses `awk` to print the line with, followed by a quote, followed by the text before the first `|` character, and finally uses `sed` to trim off everything after the last `_` and to add the trailing double quote.

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

input="${1}"
output="${2}"

cat "${input}" | tr ',' '\n' |
    sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/[()]//g' -e 's/:.*$//' |
    awk -F'|' '{ print $0"\""$1 }' |
    sed -e 's/_[^_][^_]*$/"/' > "${output}"
```

Run the script:

```
$ bash script.sh input output
```

Note the output:

```
$ cat output
AJirio_TR15329|c4_g1_i4|m.30470"AJirio"
AJama_TR16613|c5_g2_i2|m.30203"AJama"
AJkago_TR11651|c5_g2_i1|m.3847"AJkago"
AJtok_TR11413|c7_g1_i1|m.3527"AJtok"
Atab_TR15364|c0_g1_i1|m.4073"Atab"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to do it for a lot a files, I will try to automate this but so far it's working